# Evitar que Entity Framework intente insertar si existe el recurso anidado

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core

Mi caso es el siguiente, tengo una clase pedidos que tiene un cliente, yo tengo dos casos, puedo pasar un post con un cliente nuevo o puedo pasar un post con un cliente ya existente, si no existe el cliente lo va a intentar insertar, pero si existe me va a tirar error de clave.

Mi metodo de controlador

```
    [HttpPost]
public IActionResult Create([FromBody]PedidoDto pedidoDto)
{
    // map dto to entity
    var pedido = _mapper.Map<Pedido>(pedidoDto);


    try
    {
        // save 
        _pedidoService.Create(pedido);
        return Ok();
    }
    catch (AppException ex)
    {
        // return error message if there was an exception
        return BadRequest(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Mi metodo en el servicio de pedido

```
    public Pedido Create(Pedido pedido)
{
    _context.Pedidos.Add(pedido);
    _context.SaveChanges();

    return pedido;
}
```

Mis entidades pedido y cliente

```
    public class Pedido
{
    [Key]
    public int IdPedido { get; set; }
    public DateTime Fecha { get; set; }

    public Cliente Cliente { get; set; }
    public Domicilio Domicilio { get; set; }
    public Pago Pago { get; set; }
}

    public class Cliente
{
    [Key]
    public int IdCliente { get; set; }
    public string Nombre { get; set; }
    public string Apellido { get; set; }
    public int DNI { get; set; }


    public ICollection<Domicilio> Domicilios { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Telefono> Telefonos { get; set; }
}
```

Y la request

```
{
    "fecha": "2017-02-01T11:50:00",
    "cliente": {
        "idCliente": 1,
        "nombre": "Franco",
        "apellido": "Pachue",
        "dni": 365461,
        "domicilios": null,
        "telefonos": null
    },
    "domicilio": null,
    "pago": null
}
```

Mi pregunta seria como podría validar si el cliente existe y evitar el insert del EF

Comment: Haz un get de base de datos del objeto que necesitas actualizar. Si no encuentra el objeto, haces el create, pero si lo encuentra, haces un mapper de tu dto sobre el objecto que has obtenido y despues haces un update. Con eso no deberías tener problemas.

Answer (score 0):

Cambie el modelo

```
  public class Pedido
  {
    [Key]
    public int IdPedido { get; set; }
    public DateTime Fecha { get; set; }


    public int ClienteId { get; set; }
    public Cliente Cliente { get; set; }

    public Domicilio Domicilio { get; set; }
    public Pago Pago { get; set; }
    }
```

Ahora si le paso en la request el ClienteId sin el Cliente, solo inserta ese dato, en cambio si no le paso ClienteId y le paso el objeto Cliente, me crea el cliente y le agrega el pedido el ClienteId correspondiente.